# GitHub Integartion with Custom Bash Script via ssh

Tags: github, github-integration

Is it possible to integrate your own bash script into GitHub?

I'd like to set up GitHub so that any pull request would have to run via ssh a script.  This script will do all kinds of testing and my own CI/CD process.

1. How do you get GitHub to call your own, custom script?
2. How do you get GitHub to interpret the result as success or failure.
3. As a bonus it would be nice for GitHub to show the text output of the script to the user running the pull request.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) or [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) (only local).